# HP ALM new defect 500

Tags: python, rest, post, alm, hp-quality-center

With the following code, i want to create a new defect in hp alm 11.52.

```
import requests
import sys
import json

def login_alm(alm_url, login_list, header):
    # GET request @ ALM URL
    r = requests.get(alm_url + u'authentication-point/authenticate', auth = login_list)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        print 'Login successful'
        header['Cookie'] = r.headers['set-cookie']
    else:
        print'Login Failed'
        sys.exit(0)
    return header

def logout_alm(alm_url, login_list, header):
    if header['Cookie'] is not None:
        r = requests.get(alm_url + u'authentication-point/logout', headers=header, auth=login_list)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print 'Logout successful'
        else:
            print 'Logout not successful'
    else:
        print 'Logging Error: header = None'
        return 1

def create_defect(alm_url, header, alm_domain, alm_project, daten_xml, login_list):
    if header['Cookie'] is not None:
        print header
        r = requests.post(alm_url + u'rest/domains/' + alm_domain + u'/projects/' + alm_project + u'/defects',
                          headers=header,
                          data=daten_xml)


def main():
    url = u'https://{.......}'
    login = (u'{...}', u'{...}')
    domain = u'{...}'
    project = u'{...}'
    headers = {"Accept":"application/xml",
              "Content-Type":"application/xml",
              "Cookie": None}

    ticket_data_xml = ''' <Entity Type="defect">
                            <Fields>
                                <Field Name="{...}"><Value>{...}</Value></Field>
                                <Field Name="{...}"><Value>{...}</Value></Field>
                                <Field Name="{...}"><Value>{...}</Value></Field>
                                <Field Name="{...}"><Value>{...}</Value></Field>
                                <Field Name="{...}"><Value>{...}</Value></Field>
                            </Fields>
                        </Entity>'''


    headers = login_alm(alm_url=url, login_list=login, header=headers)

    create_defect(alm_url=url, header=headers, alm_domain=domain, alm_project=project, daten_xml=ticket_data_xml, login_list=login)

    logout_alm(alm_url=url, login_list=login, header=headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Login and Logout works fine, but the requests.post in the function create_defect() is the problem. Everytime I execute the code, it throws the following 500 error:

```
<QCRestException>
<Id>qccore.entity-not-found</Id>
<Title>No entity of type defect with id 703 exists.</Title>
<ExceptionProperties/>
<StackTrace>
```

The XML is correct (every required filed is included), and the Urls too. I also tried Json.

Furthermore i tried the same procedure in the Advance Rest Client for Chrome, but it still throws the same Error. Do someone know if the order of get - post - get request is correct?

QC Log, after executing:

```
at org.hp.qc.impl.services.ReadServiceImpl.read(ReadServiceImpl.java:68)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.entities.AbstractBaseResource.readEntity(AbstractBaseResource.java:325)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.entities.AbstractBaseResource.performPOSTEntity(AbstractBaseResource.java:169)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.entities.FirstLevelResource.create(FirstLevelResource.java:144)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.cache.CacheRequestHandler.handleRequest(CacheRequestHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:93)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:163)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:137)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:116)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:181)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.filters.RESTApiFilter.doFilter(RESTApiFilter.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.performance.PerformanceMonitorRESTFilter.doFilter(PerformanceMonitorRESTFilter.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.sessionmanagement.ImplicitSessionFilter.doFilter(ImplicitSessionFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.LWSSO2SpringSecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(LWSSO2SpringSecurityIntegrationFilter.java:299)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.authentication.FilterChainProxyWrapper.doFilter(FilterChainProxyWrapper.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
at com.mercury.optane.core.state.ServerStatusFilter.doFilter(ServerStatusFilter.java:35)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:941)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:312)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:936)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:663)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: could you please check and post qc log after executing this code. You will be able to get some hint out of it.

Comment: i added the qc log, but i dont get a hint out of it...

Comment: You'd have to provide the complete xml/json you used to create the defect. There may be something wrong there. Also: in Chrome, you can try this URL in one tab to authenticate: http://176.31.122.172:8888/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated?login-form-required=y After you filled in your credentials you will be able to send REST calls using the "Advanced Rest Client" add-on in another tab without having to bother with the authentication requests again.

Answer (score 0):

So the main reason why you can't create a new defect is an attempt to create already the exist defect with id #703.

Most probably you could pass in ticket_data_xml not so correctly information including tag with exist ID. It's just my assumption since you didn't give an example of your concrete data_xml.

Look at see on my example of data_xml that I used successfully on ALM 11.52 on an empty project with default customization:

```
Url:
 http://{your_server:your_port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{your_domain}/projects/{your_project}/defects
Headers:
 Content-Type=application/xml
 Accept= application/xml
Data_xml:

 <Entity Type="defect">
 <Fields>
   <Field Name="severity">
     <Value>1-Low</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field Name="name">
     <Value>Defect3</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field Name="detected-by">
     <Value>sa</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field Name="creation-time">
     <Value>2016-08-16</Value>
   </Field>
 </Fields>
 </Entity>
```

You can use this xml as example and modified it regarding required fields etc.